# Can't install qgis-server in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I had installed `QGIS 3` in the past and updated it every time in my `Ubuntu 20.04`.
Now `QGIS 3.24` is working in my system and I need to install `qgis-server` but as I run this command I got this error message:

```
sudo apt install qgis-server
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis-server : Depends: python3-qgis (= 3.10.4+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 1:3.24.1+32focal is to be installed
               Depends: qgis-providers (= 3.10.4+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 1:3.24.1+32focal is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install qgis-server`

Comment: I would first try Mayo's advice. If that does not work, give a try to the containerized version of `qgis-server` on Docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/camptocamp/qgis-server